# How to handle drop down in QTP/UFT V12.02?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

How to handle drop down in QTP/UFT V12.02 where in,
1) how to get Options count from drop down
2) how to get options (text) from Drop down

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're talking about a web item (you're not clear), try:

```
numItems = Browser("myBrowser").Page("myPage").GetROProperty("items count")

allItems = Browser("myBrowser").Page("myPage").GetROProperty("all items")
```

`allItems` will be populated as a semicolon delimited string list, which you can `Split` if you need it as an array, or `InStr` if you just want to check if an expected item is in the dropdown list.